# CTE vs Merge Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Preface, using **MS SQL Server 2008 Standard**.

I am writing an application where this stored procedure code is critical and will be called very often by many users at the same time.

The goal of the code is to update an integer column, taking into account the passed in values and matching on an integer key.

My question is, logically, which method should result in the best performance when the average list of items is 10.

I have profiled both and they seem to have similar performance with my sample data, but I am not able to simulate thousands of concurrent queries executing.

The stored procedure takes an argument of:

```
@items dbo.KeyValueTable READONLY
```

Where `KeyValueTable` is a user defined type that has two columns, `key` and `value` both of type `INT`.

CTE

```
    ;WITH itemsToCommit
    AS (
        SELECT i.[key]
            ,i.value
            ,s.committedQuantity
        FROM dbo.ItemStock s
        INNER JOIN @items i ON s.itemId = i.[key]
        )
    UPDATE itemsToCommit
    SET committedQuantity = committedQuantity + [value];
```

MERGE

```
    MERGE dbo.ItemStock AS t
    USING (
        SELECT i.[key] AS itemId
            ,i.value AS quantity
        FROM @items i
        ) AS s(itemId, quantity)
        ON t.itemId = s.itemId
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
        UPDATE
        SET t.committedQuantity = t.committedQuantity + s.quantity;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Run both of these and look both statistics io output and actual plan?

Comment: Why would you do a merge when you are only updating?  Merge was created for doing updates/inserts in the same statement.

Comment: @JamesZ Same for both: CTE does 10 logical reads and 1 scan.  Merge does 10 logical reads and 1 scan.  CPU Estimates are the same for both.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg In this case I am only interested in the update function.  Merge can also handle deletes.  Why?  Because I want to do the update over a set of data instead of RBAR.  I also want the whole statement to fail if one of the parts causes my constraint on committedQuantity to fail.

Comment: It's like using oven mitts to pick up your fork while eating.  You can do it, but why?  Don't use Merge in this case, it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Thanks for the comment and I will consider it, but I would still like to know why from a technical standpoint.